# FlatList inside SectionList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-sectionlist

I have screen with 3 different Lists, all lists have some custom header/footer and Lists contain big amount of data, so my question is - is there any performance issue with FlatList inside of SectionList?

This is rough example what i want to do

```
const App = () => {
  const renderItem = ({item, section, index}) => {
    switch (section.type) {
      case 'LIST_1':
        return (
          <View>
            <Text>Some custom set of components</Text>
            <FlatList
              data={section.items}
              renderItem={({item}) => (
                <View
                  style={{
                    padding: 20,
                    margin: 10,
                    backgroundColor: 'blue',
                  }}>
                  <Text>{item.title}</Text>
                </View>
              )}
              keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            />
          </View>
        );
      case 'LIST_2':
        return (
          <View>
            <Text>Some custom set of components</Text>
            <FlatList
              data={section.items}
              renderItem={({item}) => (
                <View
                  style={{
                    padding: 20,
                    margin: 10,
                    backgroundColor: 'red',
                  }}>
                  <Text>{item.count}</Text>
                </View>
              )}
              keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            />
          </View>
        );
      case 'LIST_3':
        return (
          <View>
            <Text>Some custom set of components</Text>
            <FlatList
              data={section.items}
              renderItem={({item}) => (
                <View
                  style={{
                    padding: 20,
                    margin: 10,
                    backgroundColor: 'blue',
                  }}>
                  <Text>{item.score}</Text>
                </View>
              )}
              keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            />
          </View>
        );
    }
  };
  const sections = [
    {
      type: 'LIST_1',
      data: [1],
      items: Array.from(Array(50)).map((el, i) => ({
        id: i + 1,
        title: i + 1,
      })),
    },
    {
      type: 'LIST_2',
      data: [2],
      items: Array.from(Array(50)).map((el, i) => ({
        id: i + 1,
        count: i + 1,
      })),
    },
    {
      type: 'LIST_3',
      data: [3],
      items: Array.from(Array(50)).map((el, i) => ({
        id: i + 1,
        score: i + 1,
      })),
    },
  ];

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <SectionList
        sections={sections}
        keyExtractor={item => item}
        renderItem={renderItem}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

If this is not optimal solution and ScrollView takes a lot of time to render, Can you guide me what is better?

Answer (score 0):

Your example can be achieved simply by using SectionList.

```
// Here we define section objects. I arbitrarily added title, footer and style.

const DATA = [
    {
        title: 'Section 1 header',
        footer: 'Section 1 footer',
        data: [...Array(3).keys()],
        style: { backgroundColor: 'red' },
    },
    {
        title: 'Section 2 header',
        footer: 'Section 2 footer',
        data: [...Array(3).keys()],
        style: { backgroundColor: 'blue' },
    },
    {
        title: 'Section 3 header',
        footer: 'Section 3 footer',
        data: [...Array(3).keys()],
        style: { backgroundColor: 'yellow' },
    },
]

// renderItem gets passed an object with item, section, index and separator keys. I'm using item and section to access my own section style.

const Item = ({ item, sectionStyle }) => (
    <View style={[styles.item, sectionStyle]}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{item}</Text>
    </View>
)

// Use renderSectionHeader and renderSectionFooter props to add, respectively, header and footer.

const App = () => (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <SectionList
            sections={DATA}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
            renderItem={({ item, section }) => <Item item={item} sectionStyle={section.style} />}
            renderSectionHeader={({ section: { title } }) => <Text style={styles.header}>{title}</Text>}
            renderSectionFooter={({ section: { footer } }) => <Text style={styles.header}>{footer}</Text>}
        />
    </SafeAreaView>
)
```

And to answer your original question, you might run into performance issues with react-natives list components, it depends on many factors, including your data and rendered components.

You can read more on the topic here:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration

Comment: Sorry, i had to wrote more accurate example. my render Items are very different and they have wrapper elements that style them differently

Comment: Well, that's not a problem either and my example still stands. Depending on how much your items differ, you can either pass a style, like I did or you can conditionally render a different component altogether. Check this snack: https://snack.expo.dev/spQ8U9Q6U

Comment: What should if I want to render first list horizontal, second not and etc? that's my last question. Thank you so far!

Comment: I guess then you do have to nest lists. Have your first sections data array consist of one object, that has all the necessary fields to construct a FlatList inside your renderItem function. Inside renderItem, create a condition for rendering FlatList, if section === x.

Comment: So that's what I'm doing in my example right? So there is no performance issues?

Comment: Well, I think I am lacking information on what you're trying to do. You probably don't need to have 3 different FlatList components inside your renderItem. Performance-wise, answer is, you might have performance issues. I provided a link with more information.

Comment: I'll try to create figma design for example

Comment: This is wireframe of what i want to achieve  - https://www.figma.com/file/gYoehX7bGORD3Xa4AsJTfG/Untitled?node-id=0%3A1

Comment: How I would create that example, no optimizations https://snack.expo.dev/kb1CPwF-u